# Performing partial update on innermost document using mongo db c# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am having a Mongo-DB model that has multi-level nested collections. ie. In a project collection, i have screen collection and in screen collection i have buttons collection,label collection,checkbox collection and so on. A sample model is as follows,

```
    {
     "ProjectUId": "sample string 1",
     "ProjectName": "sample string 2",
     "LastUpdate": "2014-01-13T10:46:14.6693626+05:30",
     "Screens": [
      {
      "UId": "sample string 1",
      "Id": "sample string 2",
      "ScreenOrientation": {
      "LandscapeId": "sample string 1",
      "PortraitId": "sample string 2",
      "Buttons": [           
        {
        "BId": "sample string 1",
        "Id": "sample string 2",
        "Name":"sample string 3",
        },
        {
        }
        .
        .
        .
        }
```

So my problem is i am finding it difficult to update only a Button document of button collection having Bid=B0001 using mongo db c# driver
Can any one help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check sintax, because I have not Mongo to test here

```
MongoCollection<BsonDocument> screens;

var query = new QueryDocument {
    //Guessing that Bid is unique. If more "screens" can have the same button add
    // items to this filter
    { "Buttons.Bid", "B0001" }
};

var update = new UpdateDocument {
    //By using positional operator that updates only the array member that match query
    { "$set", new BsonDocument("Buttons.$.Name", "New Sample string") }
};

BsonDocument updatedScreens = screens.Update(query, update);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this, and it's not a C# driver limitation, it's a limitation of the MongoDB query language. Essentially the problem is you can't use "$" in the update portion because you would need more than one "$" (due to the multiple levels of nesting).

The easiest solution will be to bring the entire document client side and update the client side objects in memory and then save the entire document back to the database.

As an optimization, you could construct an update statement that modified only the relevant Button field, something like:

```
var screenIndex = 0; // you would have to determine this value
var buttonIndex = 0; // you would have to determine this value
var buttonName = string.Format("Screens.{0}.Buttons.{1}.Name", screenIndex, buttonIndex);
var query = Query.EQ("ProjectUId", "...");
var update = Update.Set(buttonName, "new name");
var result = collection.Update(query, udpate);
```

Essentially what this is doing is compensating for the fact that you can't use multiple "$" in the field name by computing the indexes client side.